# Как использовать методы класса, ссылка на который содержится в массиве?

Tags: c#, массивы, ссылки

Столкнулся со следующим вопросом на стадии изучения C#. Есть массив, в котором содержатся два поля класса и ссылка на сам класс.

```
public void AddAllItems()
{
    allItems[0, 0] = Blade.itemName;
    allItems[0, 1] = Blade.cost;
    allItems[0, 2] = new Blade();            
}
```

Мне необходимо перебрать элементы из него, и так как я знаю, на каком месте (второй индекс) будет ссылка на класс, хочу вызвать метод `Build()` этого класса.
Как мне это сделать?
`allItems[i, 2].Build()`, естественно, не работает, так как он не знает заранее, что это будет ссылка на класс, как я понимаю.
Что именно я делаю не так и как мне поступить?

```
public void Sell(string itemName)
{
    if (inventory.Contains(itemName))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < allItems.Length; i++)
        {
            if (allItems[i, 0].ToString() == itemName)
            {
                allItems[i, 2].Build();
                purse += (int)allItems[i, 1] / 2;
                Console.WriteLine($"Great! You've sold {itemName} for {(int)allItems[i, 1]}!");                                                
                Console.WriteLine($"Your money: {purse}\n");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You don't have this in your inventory!\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите для начала массив allItems

Comment: `allItems[0, 0] = Blade.itemName;
            allItems[0, 1] = Blade.cost;
            allItems[0, 2] = new Blade();
            allItems[1, 0] = Katana.itemName;
            allItems[1, 1] = Katana.cost;
            allItems[1, 2] = new Katana();
            allItems[2, 0] = Knife.itemName;
            allItems[2, 1] = Knife.cost;
            allItems[2, 2] = new Knife();`

Comment: Круто, но я просил показать что он вообще из себя представляет, а не что в нем вы записали

Comment: Прошу прощения, единственное, что еще касается массива в коде, это вот это: `public static object[,] allItems = new object[4, 4];`

Comment: Хорошо, это и нужно было.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:
Сделайте для начала Interface для ваших вещей.
Пусть это будет IItem:

```
public interface IItem
{
    int Cost { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    void Build();
}
```

И используйте данный интерфейс в кач-ве массива:

```
class YourImplementationForIItem : IItem
{
    public int Cost { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void Build() => Console.WriteLine("Build method");
}

IItem[] items = new IItem[1];

items[0] = new YourImplementationForIItem
{
    Cost = 100,
    Name = "Knife"
};

items[0].Build();
```